# using axios in service object in React Native fails

Tags: react-native, axios

I can't figure out why this does not work. I think it has to do with having a promise nested inside another promise:

I set up my api service object:

```
api.js

import axios from 'axios';
import apiConfig from './apiConfig';
import deviceStorage from '../services/deviceStorage.js';

export const get = (endpoint, payload = {}, headers = {}) => {
  const jwt = deviceStorage.loadJWT

  headers.Authorization = jwt
  console.log("running..");

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: apiConfig.development.url + endpoint,
    headers: headers,
    data: payload,
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log('will return response..');
    return response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('will return error..');
    return error;
  });
};
```

then I call it from a screen:

```
NotificationsScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import NotificationCardSection from '../components/notificationsScreen/NotificationCardSection';
import NotificationCardList from '../components/notificationsScreen/NotificationCardList';
import { Loading } from '../components/common/';
import globalStyles from '../globalStyles';
import * as api from '../services/api'

export default class NotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      notifications: [],
      error: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("will get data from api");
    api.get(
      '/notifications'
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log("got back data from api");
      this.setState({
        notifications: response.data.data,
        loading: false
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("got error from api");
      this.setState({
        error: 'Error retrieving data',
        loading: false
      });
    });
  }
```

but i get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.
```

terminal shows `'running..'` but does not show `'will return response...'` or `'will return error'` so they are not firing.

I assume it is because the api call has not finished yet, but since it is async, how can I make sure it HAS finished when calling it from the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting a `Promise` to be returned from your `get` since you are using `then` and `catch` on it but you are just returning a response or an error.

Your `get` function should look like the below if you want to use `.then` with it:

```
export const get = (endpoint, payload = {}, headers = {}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const jwt = deviceStorage.loadJWT

      headers.Authorization = jwt
      console.log("running..");

      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiConfig.development.url + endpoint,
        headers: headers,
        data: payload,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('will return response..');
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('will return error..');
        reject(error);
     });
 });
};
```

Comment: thanks. that makes sense and does resolve the error but now, only the loading icon is shown in screen. checking the terminal, "will get data from api" and "running..." are shown but nothing else. API logs show no API call is being made

Comment: ok, hardcoding the url worked so it seems it's something else going on. thanks for your help!